# Google Sheets: Copy a cell into the first blank cell in a column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to copy from cell A2, which is a forever changing formula, because it captures =NOW()
and copy that as value in first blank cell in column B. I have tried Last row, but becasue I do have data in other columns on the same row then it will jump to the actual first empty row. I just need that cell.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NOW() | **value** |  |
|  | *THIS IS WHERE I NEED NOW TO GO* | **value** |

```
function copy() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var svA=ss.getRange('A2').getValue();
  var tsh=ss.getSheetByName('SheetName');
  tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,2).setValue(svA);
  }`
```

I have tried the above table and it skipped B2 and went to B3 because I have data in C2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,2).setValue(svA);
```

With

```
let last = tsh.getRange("B1").getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
tsh.getRange(last.getNumRows()+1,2).setValue(svA)
```

Comment: This was the answer! Works like a charm :)